# How to show that all roots of $(11+v)q^3-18q^2+9q-2$ have their absolute value less than 1.

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

The equation is $(11+v)q^3-18q^2+9q-2=0$, where $v>0$

I need to show that either absolute value of all the roots is not greater than one or there exists a root $q: |q|>1$.

Using Weierstrass theorem I showed that there is a real root $q\in[0;1]$.

Using derivative I showed that there are no real roots in $(-\infty,0)\cup(1;+\infty)$.

As Cardano's theorem states, there are three possibilities:

1. All three roots are distinct and real. If I have this situation, I'm done because all $q\in[0;1]$
2. Two distinct roots (three real roots of which one is counted twice). The same situation is above.
3. One real root and two complex roots.

In the third situation is there possibility that $|q|>1$ for some complex root of the equation in question?

Comment: $q=1$ is not a solution. Hence either the absolute values of all roots is not greater than one or there exists a root with the absolute value strictly greater than one.

Comment: I meant here exclusive "or": I need to show either the first one or the second one but not both. And the question below is what I'm stuck in.

Comment: The question I'm asking at the moment is written in the bottom of the text. If this equation has one real root and two comlex roots, what can I say about the complex ones?

Comment: The [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Formula_2) of the equation is $-108(v^2 - 5v + 13)$, which is always negative if $v$ is real, thus there will always be two complex roots.

Comment: It's clear but I need to compate their absolute values with $1$. It's the part that I can't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ First show that the real root lies in the interval $(\frac{2}{11+v},1)$. Then think about the product of the three roots.

Comment: All are less than one in their absolute value. Thank you for the help